# Problems with using gperftools on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, profiling, profile, gperftools

I have found several conflicting answers over this topic. [This](https://dudefrommangalore.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/profiling-c-code-using-google-performance-tools/#unwind) blog post requires libuwind, but that doesn't work on Mac OS X. I included `#include <google/profiler.h>` in my code, however my compiler (g++) could not find the library. I installed `gperftools` via homebrew. In addition, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562280/line-number-in-google-perftools-cpu-profiler-on-macosx) stackoverflow question showing this:

> Then I ran pprof to generate the output:
>
> ```
> [hidden ~]$ pprof --text ./a.out cpu.profile 
> Using local file ./a.out.
> Using local file cpu.profile.
> Removing __sigtramp from all stack traces.
> Total: 282 samples
>      107  37.9%  37.9%      107  37.9% 0x000000010d72229e
>       16   5.7%  43.6%       16   5.7% 0x000000010d721a5f
>       12   4.3%  47.9%       12   4.3% 0x000000010d721de8
> ...
> ```

Running that command (without any of the prior steps) gets me this:

```
[hidden]$ pprof --text ./a.out cpu.profile 
Using remote profile at ./a.out.
Failed to get the number of symbols from http://cpu.profile/pprof/symbol
```

Why does it try to access an internet site on my machine and a local file on his/hers?

Attempting to link lib profiler as a dry run with g++ gets me:

```
[hidden]$ g++ -l libprofiler
ld: library not found for -llibprofiler
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have looked at the man pages, the help option text, the official online guide, blog posts, and many other sources.

I am so confused right now. Can someone help me use gperftools?

*The result of my conversation with @osgx was [this script](https://gist.github.com/CrazyPython/359528e67531e895e2ed945ad2e8f5c4). I tried to clean it up a bit. It likely contains quite a few unnecessary options too.*

Comment: Hi, user uo... Can you list all files of gperftools installed via homebrew (or just full log or make install)? How did you try *link* your program to be profiled with cpu profiler  of gperftools library? (the blog missed this part, check http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/cpu_profiler.html "*Linking in the Library .. add `-lprofiler` to the link-time step for your executable. (It's also probably possible to add in the profiler at run-time using `LD_PRELOAD`, but this isn't necessarily recommended.)*") Did you have cpu.profile file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog post https://dudefrommangalore.wordpress.com/2012/02/09/profiling-c-code-using-google-performance-tools/ "Profiling C++ code using Google Performance Tools" 2012 by  dudefrommangalore missed the essential step.

You should *link* your program (which you want to be profiled) with cpu profiler library of gperftools library.

Check official manual: http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/cpu_profiler.html, part "Linking in the Library"

> add `-lprofiler` to the link-time step for your executable. (It's also probably possible to add in the profiler at run-time using `LD_PRELOAD`, but this isn't necessarily recommended.)

Second step is to collect the profile, run the code with profiling enabled. In linux world it was done by setting controlling environment variable `CPUPROFILE` before running:

```
CPUPROFILE=name_of_profile ./program_to_be_profiled
```

Third step is to use `pprof` (`google-pprof` in [ubuntu world](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/google-pprof.1.html)). Check that there is not-empty `name_of_profile` profile file generated; it there is no such file, pprof will try to do remote profile fetch (you see output of such try).

```
pprof ./program_to_be_profiled name_of_profile
```

Comment: `libuwind` is not supported on Mac OS X. [source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27842377/building-libunwind-for-mac)

Comment: I also could not resolve `#include <google/profiler>`

Comment: Can you try to compile gperftools without libunwind? It is needed to readout call stack and to draw callgraph; without it it is possible to get flat profile (reading pc on profiling signal). You may use gpreftools without including `google/profiler.h` (the blog post is partially incorrect), just with preloading or linking with the lib, the lib wil turn on profiling in its init if the CPUPROFILE env var is set. Please, post full log of make install of gperftools.

Comment: I'm a real noob to C++, could you please tell me which command is the link-time step? do I do it for `gcc`? `gperftools` installed successfully. do you still want a full log? by the way, thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Please, add detail about your installation of gperftools on OSX ("I installed gperftools via homebrew"), and show the OSX version. I have no live OSX at the moment and can't reproduce the installation. I need to know what and where is installed to help you (to find exact library name and path to it). Compiling step has `-c` option and is like `gcc ... -c -o file.o` and linking step has executable file name in `-o` option, it is like `gcc file.o file2.o -o executable` (sometimes both are combined). Post linking command output with `-v` option added (verbose - it will print library search path).

Comment: OS X El Captain v10.11.5 (latest version). I believe I've made some progress. Linking + running *appears* to have succeeded. [Here](https://gist.github.com/CrazyPython/f067eaa0172621bcb5f4c13fe3906b51) is the linking command output and also the profiling output. It could find `-lprofiler` now for some magical reason.

Comment: If this works, you could adapt it to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308174/command-line-profiling-tool-for-mac-os-x) I put a bounty on, I will award it to that answer

Comment: Update: I couldn't upload the profiling to Github Gists ("contents can't be empty" even though it's non-empty), possibly because it starts with Unicode characters. On [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/a4qqj4xz). Stripped unicode output: [a bunch of squares that get converted to nothing when I post them on any site, including here]'7fff9ce27000-7fffa296d000 r-xp 1b120000 00:00 0           /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib

Comment: upload "profiling"? What is it? Please, don't upload library itself. If you were able to link, run  `CPUPROFILE=profilefile ./your_program` (program should run longer than 0.5s), check that profilefile is generated and not empty and run `pprof on it`. The "this question" was not your, so no. Posted gist "CrazyPython/f067eaa0172621bcb5f4c13fe3906b51" is not linking step, it is compiling (`-emit-obj  -o ..file.o`) by clang; I need linking log. What was uploaded to pastebin? It is /proc/pid/maps only... (part of profile)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116006/discussion-between-uohtypyzarc-and-osgx).

Answer (score 1):

First you need to run your program with profiling enabled.

This is usually first linking your program with libprofiler and then running it with CPUPROFILE=cpu.profile.

I.e.

$ CPUPROFILE=cpu.profile my_program

I think that later step is what you have been missing.

The program will create this cpu.profile file when it exits. And then you can use pprof (preferably from github.com/google/pprof) on it to visualize/analyze.

Comment: First is to inject cpu profiling library inside the program. Either by linking it directly with profiling library or by using LD_PRELOAD (how it is called in Darwin/OSX?). And running is the second step, CPUPROFILE env var will enable profiling, only if the library is linked into program.